# Fetch an array into another array PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i want to fetch an array into another array without using foreach

```
   $data[0]['name']="name1";
   $data[0]['age']=10;
   $data[1]['name']="name2";
   $data[1]['age']=11;
   $data[2]['name']="name3";
   $data[2]['age']=12;
```

i want to fetch array $data into $user so that $user become..

```
   $user['name']="name1";
   $user['age']=10;
```

without using 'foreach' statement.

Comment: you mean like `$user = $data[0]` ?

Comment: .. or even `$user =& $data[0]` ?

Comment: yes,and loop it without foreach loop

Comment: What exactly do you want to loop with constant index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `foreach` you say...

```
reset($data);
$max = count($data);

for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    list($key, $user) = each($data);
    // do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$user = $data[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

No foreach loop:

```
<?php
while( $user = array_shift( $data ) ) {
  print_r( $user );
}
```

But then, why do you have such an odd requirement? After all, foreaches are just the tool for a job like this. Are we, by any chance, doing your homework? ;)

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` actually represents `for` and `each`:

```
for (reset($data); list($key, $user) = each($data);) {
###                                    ####
    // do stuff.
}
```